# C# Rich Text Box Error No overload for method appendtext takes two arguments

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to display the current memory available in c# in a rich text box, but i get the error no overload for method appendtext takes two arguments. Could someone show me how to fix?

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentAvailableMemory = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();
        richTextBox1.AppendText("There are currently {0} megabytes of memory available/r/n", currentAvailableMemory.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `AppendText` only takes a string parameter, use this:

```
 richTextBox1.AppendText(
     string.Format(
         "There are currently {0} megabytes of memory available/r/n", 
          currentAvailableMemory
      ));
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of other methods (like `Console.WriteLine()`) implicitly call [`String.Format`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format) (or at least provide an overload that accepts the String.Format argument list).  [Append Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) isn't one of them, so you'll need to explicitly use String.Format like this

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(
     String.Format("There are currently {0} megabytes of memory available/r/n", 
         currentAvailableMemory.ToString()));
```